# Are the LinkWidth attacks still a threat?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, exit-relays, attacks

Recently i have found a pdf talking about an attack using so-called “LinkWidth” against tor network, here it is https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/aa31/f6e8676e6c1a531854e4337649f0556e9280.pdf

The authors claim, that they can uncover client IP using it, but is it even practical to do what they propoe nowadays?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible for attacks of that kind to succeed. No, it doesn't seem to be currently practical. As of around 2011 (3 years after this paper was published) even [the NSA was reporting difficulty](https://edwardsnowden.com/docs/doc/tor-stinks-presentation.pdf) with deanonymizing Tor users.

> We will never be able to deanonymize all Tor users all the time
>
> With manual analysis we can deanonymize a very small fraction of Tor users, however, **no** success de-anonymizing a user [on demand].

This is already covered in the [Tor Project FAQ](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#AttacksOnOnionRouting).

> ... it is possible for an observer who can view both you and either the destination website or your Tor exit node to correlate timings of your traffic as it enters the Tor network and also as it exits. Tor does not defend against such a threat model.